# Python: How do I do menu option spacing in a way that the options are centered?

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry english not first language:

I started python today in school and I can't figure this out, I am also specified to use procedural programming, so I can't call in classes like .textwrap or .format.

Here's the code:

```
x_max = 0
y_max = 0
menu = ["1. Somma", "2. Sottrazione", "3. Moltiplicazione", "4. Divisione", "5. Exit"]
y_max = len(menu)
for x in range(len(menu)):
  p = len(menu[x])
  if (x_max < p):
    x_max = p

x_tabella = x_max

print("╔", end = '')
for x in range (x_tabella+4):
  print ("═", end = '')
print ("╗")

for x in range(y_max):
  print ("║  ", end = '')
  print (menu[x], end = '') != x_max
  print ("  ║")

print("╚", end = '')
for x in range (x_tabella+4):
  print ("═", end = '')
print ("╝")
```

The objective is to put a border, like a menu around the options, with the options centered in the borders. The problem is I don't know how to center it properly, cause the left side looks fine, but the right side is all off center. It's supposed to be a code where whatever option you put into the menu it extends and adapts the border.

[This is how it ends up currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMYKZ.png)

I would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: If you want to try it yourself: in the code block following `for x in range(y_max):`, you print the "menu item", and then the right border. However, all menu items have different length, and the border is just two spaces away. You need to increase the number of the empty spaces accordingly, to match the box size.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't really understand your intention with this line:

`print (menu[x], end = '') != x_max`

But change it to:

`print(menu[x] + ' '*(x_max-len(menu[x])), end = '')`

And you should get the expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed it